# Does VMware Workstation support PCI Passthrough with the VT-d technology?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, vt-d

Does the `VMware Workstation` v15.5.1 support `USB Passthrough` on a Host composed of the `Z68x chipset` with `Intel i7-3770 CPU`, which has the `VT-d` feature enabled (also known as: `IOMMU virtualization`) ?

The USB controller is the `NEC/Renesas µPD720202` chip, connected to the CPU via the PCI Express bus.

Comment: If I plug a USB key into my host computer, VMware Workstation will ask me if the Guest should have the USB key or the Host should have the USB key. So as I understand your question, yes, passthrough is supported.  Hardware virtualization is required for 64-bit guests, but that is independent of USB passthrough.

Comment: Exclusive ownership of the "USB key" does not guarantee, that the information from the USB port is passed to the `Guest OS` at high speed using the `IOMMU virtualization` technology.  The same behavior (but not speed) can be accomplished by the Hypervisor taking an exclusive ownership of the USB port and acting as a **slow** software intermediary/relay to the Guest OS.

Comment: VMWare supports VT-d; What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I don't think it matters how the USB Port is connected inside. If you can use a standard USB Key or USB Hard drive in it, then it can pass through in VMware. If this is not what you are looking for, please let us know how we may assist you.